# Probability of segment lying in circle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, geometric-probability

Given a circle of radius R: $x^2+y^2\le R$, find probability of horizontal segment with length $\frac{R}{2}$ lie whole inside this circle. Position of segment's center has uniform distribution in circle.

Okay, I draw circle for $R=1$:

[image]

Red circle is circle of radius R, green circle is area where center of segment should be in order to be in circle. So I think, that probability is:
$$P=\frac{\pi(\frac{R}{2})^2}{\pi R^2}=\frac{1}{4}$$

But answer in the book is $\frac{(4\pi-3\sqrt3)}{6\pi}$

Where I am wrong?

Comment: The segment center does not have to lie in the green circle...

Comment: The green circle just tell you that if it is inside the red circle, then if the segment has 1 end at the center of the green circle, then it must be inside the red circle. Think about when 2 ends both lie on the red circle and see why this method does not work.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I forgot, that segment is horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the segment is horizontal and its length equals $R$, the allowed positions for its centre are given by the region depicted below:

[image]

where the area of the upper and lower circular segment together is given by $$\frac{\pi}{3}R^2-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}R^2,$$
so the area of the striped region is given by the area of the circle, minus the previous area, minus the area of a rectangle having base $R$ and height $\sqrt{3}\, R$ by the Cavalieri's principle, so the area of the striped region equals:
$$\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\sqrt{3}\right)R^2 = \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)R^2 $$
and the wanted probability is indeed:
$$ \frac{4\pi-3\sqrt{3}}{6\pi}\approx 39.1\% $$
as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

Considering vertical line feels better to me, but there is no difference.

Consider the midpoint of the segment. Since it cannot be closer to the red circle than $\frac{1}{4}$, what is the area that you can place the center of segment? The region between $\sqrt{1-x^2} - \frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{4} - \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Therefore you just do integration to find out the area.

By symmetry:

$$A = 4 \int^\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}_4 \sqrt{1-x^2} - \frac{1}{4} dx$$

which yields the wrong answer.

But I tried the segment length with $R$, in this case you can yield the correct answer. Now you subtract $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{4}$ and the upper bound of integration is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. The area is $\frac{4 \pi - 3\sqrt{3}}{6}$, and the area of circle is $\pi$.

(Jack D'Aurizio's picture clearly shows that the length of segment is $R$.)